# Como não deixar uma imagem carregar no javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma página mais só quero que as imagens dela carregue quando o usuário executar uma ação. Tem alguma função no javascript ou jquery para fazer isso ?

Comment: Você pode deixar a imagem com ´style="display: block"´ e alterar para ´style="display: none"´ quando sua função for executada.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode deixar a imagem com `style="display: none"` e alterar para `style="display: block"` quando sua função for executada.

```js
function funcaoExibir(){
  img.style.display='block';
}

function funcaoOcultar(){
  img.style.display='none';
}
```

```html
Botão que aciona função para exibir imagem: <input type='button' onclick='funcaoExibir()' value='click.me'></br>
Botão que aciona função para ocultar imagem: <input type='button' onclick='funcaoOcultar()' value='click.me'></br>
<img id='img' src="http://big.assets.huffingtonpost.com/pikatchuto.gif" style="display: none" >
```

---

Você também pode retardar o carregamento da imagem utilizando um `document.createElement('img');` e atribuindo o `src` após a execução da função que você desejar, assim:

```js
var i = 0;

function criarImagens(){
  i++;
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.id = 'img'+i;
  img.src = 'http://big.assets.huffingtonpost.com/pikatchuto.gif';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
Botão que cria a imagem dinamicamente: <input type='button' onclick='criarImagens()' value='click.me'></br>
```

Se as suas imagens seguirem uma ordem numérica, no `src` você poderia atribuir assim:  `img.src='pathDasImagens/img'+i+'.jpg';`

---

Ai também vai um pouco da sua criatividade, se quiser que as imagens sejam carregadas com o rolar da página poderia fazer assim:

```js
var i = 0;

window.onscroll= function() {
  i++;
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.id = 'img'+i;
  img.src = 'http://big.assets.huffingtonpost.com/pikatchuto.gif';
  document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

```html
<div style="height:2000px;"></div>
```

Comment: O problema é o seguinte a página tem umas 200 imagens e mesmo com o display:block; ela carrega as imagens do mesmo jeito eu não quero que elas carreguem de imediato quero que o usuário clique em um dos botões que correspondem a um evento da empresa e essas imagens carreguem a partir desse clique. Entendeu ?

Comment: Editado com alguns modos de se obter o mesmo resultado